# UIScrollView scrollRectToVisible:animated: is there a way that a method can be called when animation ends

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Is there a way to know when the animation has end and uiscrollview has come to rest.

Comment: Regarding this very old question, nowadays there are THREE situations which must be covered. It's one of the strangest and most difficult issues in iOS.  :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yup use [scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:)

Comment: It doesn't get called everytime ex. when scrollRectToVisible() is called inside traitCollationDidChange

Comment: This is wrong, there are three separate cases to cover.

Comment: I agree with @Fattie's comment because there are multiple scenarios which scrolling can end. This answer is not as good as Fattie's answer below.

Comment: @Fattie Yes, and for some reason SO bot decides to remove 1 reputation from me. Anyway, just wanted to thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 13):

I do it like this because sometimes using the delegate isn't practical for me, like if i'm doing it in UIViewController transition:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -scrollView.contentInset.top) animated:NO];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // This is called when it's complete
}];
```

Comment: Exactly! I also used the same code only then it worked as per expectation.

Comment: I put my cell modification code into the `completion` but my `animation` and `completion` are executing line by line. not working as expected :(

Comment: unfortunately, this will literally crash in many circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

Implement [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation%3a) delegate methods for your UIScrollView the following way:

Use `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` to detect when the scrolling animation concludes when you've initiated the scrolling by calling `setContentOffset:animated:` or  `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` methods (with animated:YES).

If you want to monitor scroll view motion that's been initiated by touch gestures, use `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` method, which is called when the scrolling movement comes to a halt.

Comment: for anyone googling here, this very old answer is now **incorrect** - thanks, Apple!  :/

Answer (score 3):

## You need to cover THREE (!) cases. Thanks, Apple.

```
// do note that you need all three of the following

public func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ s: UIScrollView) {
    // covers case setContentOffset/scrollRectToVisible
    fingerOrProgrammaticMoveDone()
}

public func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ s: UIScrollView, willDecelerate d: Bool) {
    if decelerate == false {
        // covers certain cases of user finger
        fingerOrProgrammaticMoveDone()
    }
}

public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ s: UIScrollView) {
    // covers certain cases of user finger
    fingerOrProgrammaticMoveDone()
}
```

(Be careful to not forget the extra "if" clause in the middle one.)

Then in `fingerOrProgrammaticMoveDone()` , do what you need.

A good example of this is the nightmare of handling paged scrolling.  It is very, very hared to know what page you are on.

Answer (score -2):

`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` UIScrollView delegate method is called when scrollView stops completely.